# yii ajax renderpartial with form validation

Tags: ajax, yii, renderpartial, yii-extensions

I have a dropdown list in yii that depending on the id renders some additional fields (that requests other models).

How can I use the $form field in those (it's Yii-Bootstrap) so that I can have the validation messages (via $form->errorSummary() ) and not implementing my own javascript messages?

Comment: Do you want validation/error messages for the dropdown list? If you want error messages for the partially rendered inputs, create rules in the models.

Comment: For the partially rendered inputs. But the real problem is that because I don't have a reference to the $form in the ajax call (and that's correct) I can't render the form elements with the form naming and stuff. I had to reverse engineer the form to create the elements (Using the same name convention and custom ids)

Comment: it's all a little unclear, can you post some code, namely the view(s) for forms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking for, but it seems like it's related to rendering form fields/errors and validation. As far as specifing custom selector fields goes, look into [CHthml::activeDropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail), it'll let you define your drop list items accordingly. As for validation, you can validate that drop down by making it have it's own validation rule and error as described here:[Custom Model Validators](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/). This will allow you to use CHtml::errorSummary($model) as the dropdown will return an appropriate error message if it's validation fails...

Cheers,
Fy

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but renderPartial() has serious issues with AJAX:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/10427-ajax-clientscript